# How do I programmatically create a route?

Tags: 8, routes

I'm trying to create a route programmatically using this code.

#### example.routing.yml

```
route_callbacks:
    - '\Drupal\example\Routing\ExampleRoutes::routes'
```

#### Drupal\example\Routing\ExampleRoutes.php

```
namespace Drupal\example\Routing;

use Symfony\Component\Routing\Route;

class ExampleRoutes {
    public function routes() {
        $routes = array();
        $routes['example.settings'] = new Route(
            '/example/',
            array(
              '_form' => '\Drupal\example\Form\ExampleForm',
            ),
            array(
              '_permission'  => 'access content',
            )
        );

        return $routes;
    }

}
```

When I install the module, I get the following error

> Class \Drupal\example\Routing\ExampleRoutes does not exist

Why doesn't the above code work?

Comment: Is the folder structure of the module correct?

Comment: Hi Kevin, yes as far as I can see. As you can see above, the paths are correct

Comment: The file should live at “mymodule/src/Routing/“

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Comment: Why are you attempting to create it like this indead of using [.routing.yml](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/introductory-drupal-8-routes-and-controllers-example) file?

Answer (score 3):

I think that in your case the problem is in this line:

```
    '/example/',
```

that should be:

```
    '/example',
```

so without the final `/`.

You can try with the other method extending from `RouteSubscriberBase` and your routes method needs to receive as a parameter a `RouteCollection`.

```
use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteSubscriberBase;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

class ExampleRoutes extends RouteSubscriberBase {

  public function routes(RouteCollection $collection) {

  }

}
```

And you need to define the Route Subscriber as a service

```
  example.route_subscriber:
    class: Drupal\example\Routing\ExampleRoutes
    tags:     - { name: event_subscriber }
```

Take a look at this example:

[Dynamic Routes in Drupal 8 with a RouteSubscriber](https://www.previousnext.com.au/blog/dynamic-routes-drupal-8-routesubscriber)

Comment: The question is asking why the code causes that error. It's correct to use a route callback, since it is also used from Drupal core modules.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I know my answer first part solve the problem and I added anohter way after.

Comment: I didn't mean it was wrong, but that should make clearer the approach shown in the question works too, once fixed the behind error. The error message shown in the question appears before the new route is added. The trailing slash in a string doesn't avoid Drupal finds the class, since to find the string Drupal should first find the class, but it's the class that Drupal doesn't find.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following example it works for me.

**example.routing.yml**

```
route_callbacks:
  - '\Drupal\example\Routing\ExampleRoutes::routes'
```

**src/Routing/ExampleRoutes.php**

```
namespace Drupal\example\Routing;

use Symfony\Component\Routing\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

class ExampleRoutes{

  public function routes(){
    $route_collection = new RouteCollection();
    $route            = new Route(
    // Path to attach this route to:
      'example',
      // Route defaults:
      [
        '_form' => 'Drupal\example\Form\ExampleForm',
      ],
      // Route requirements:
      [
        '_permission' => 'access content',
      ]
    );
    $route_collection->add('example.settings', $route);
    return $route_collection;
  }

}
```

Note that path param 'example' shouldn't have any '/' .